# Android: Highlight A Sentence in Paragraph When Long Clicked

Tags: android, highlight, textselection

I know we can make `textView` clickable. When someone opens a news article on `WebView` and long clicks a sentence in a paragraph, I'd like to give the user the chance to highlight it for future reference or add a comment to it. For this purpose, where should I store every sentence in a paragraph when the website is loaded? Should I use `textviews` for every sentence and call `OnLongClickListener()`?

```
tv.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener(){

    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        // what to do here?
    }
});
```

I'd appreciate any tips! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

There can be many ways to implement this highlighting. It depends on your choice - whether you want to show a dialog box to do something or show a small fragment or anything else. But to Highlight the Text you can use the XML Tag-
android:textColorHighlight.

Accessing it on Java side-
textView1.setHighlightColor(Color_Goes_Here);

For further reading, refer the documentation-
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setHighlightColor(int)

EDIT: CLARIFICATION OF QUESTION

Just to be sure - you need just the highlighting functionality or you need help creating the popup which occurs when user selects the text. From what I understood now, you should have a look at registerForContextMenu.

Register your text view using 
    registerForContextMenu(_TextView_Goes_Here);
Then simply override the 
    onCreateContextMenu()

Your text can then be copied, pasted, or do whatever you want with the text. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html

Comment: I guess I couldn't ask the question clearly. I am talking about a textview that contains more than 1 sentence (like a paragraph). I need to be able to pick 1 sentence from that text when clicked.